# "for + noun phrase" vs "of + noun phrase"

Tags: prepositions

> [presumptive (adj)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/presumptive?q=presumptive) 1.1 *Law*
>   Giving grounds **for** the inference of a fact or **of** the appropriate interpretation of the law.

Would someone please explain why **of** precedes the second noun phrase (the appropriate interpretation of the law) ? Why not 'for' again, which precedes the first noun phrase? Why doesn't 'for' apply equally to the second?

**Afterword:** A comma would've elucidated the confusion, that I now insert as [,]:
Giving grounds **for** the inference[,] of a fact OR of the appropriate interpretation of the law.

Comment: That's not the second noun phrase. That's the third. The second noun phrase is _of a fact_, and it's disjoined with _or of the appropriate interpretation of the law_. Both prepositional phrases with _of_ modify _inference_. So what the phrase really says is _Giving grounds for the inference of a fact, or giving grounds for the inference of the appropriate interpretation of the law._ Got all that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As John Lawler's comment indicates, the phrase "of the appropriate interpretation of the law" is in parallel with the phrase "of a fact" (with both phrases sprouting from the word *inference*); it is NOT in parallel with the phrase "for the inference of a fact" (with both phrases supposedly sprouting from the word *grounds*).

Consequently, spelling out the sentence with the shared trunk repeated for clarity, you would get this:

> Giving grounds for the inference of a fact, or giving grounds for the inference of the appropriate interpretation of the law.

and NOT this:

> Giving grounds for the inference of a fact, or giving grounds of the appropriate interpretation of the law.